# How do you limit Exceptions loggings in production

Tags: logging, monitoring

First, please note this might be a JavaScript question, on Node or on the browser, or a Ruby question, whether logging is in files or to the database, etcetera.
This is why I'm asking in *serverfault*; Because I assume many people here are concerned with monitoring apps in production ! If there is another Stackexchange site, kindly ask and I will port it there.

How do you deal with long exceptions messages when logging. There are two types of exceptions: those you would raise yourself (and have a relatively good control over their messages) and others raised by dependencies.

I personally, have a limited experience going on production but I'm thinking of:

1. Limit logging to error.message (rather than the whole stack)
2. Simply put a strict limit on the message length (`err.message.split(0, 100)` for example)

Next, what I think of as an ambitious solution but not sure at all, is to wrap any exception with a generic home made one, that would strip long messages, also lower the depth of the stack, and even more, it would handle exceptions loggings stuck in a loop (putting a timer and a counter or each raised exception).

I did never think of logging as a real problem, until now, and maybe I'm making things complex.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to avoid/forbid repetitive logging in programming. Connection refused error, for example, will persist if auto-reconnecting is a feature. I always emphasize that no connection is a state and only need to be logged once, and getting connected would result another log, totally two logs would suffice, rather than endless no connection line by line. If you cannot enforce the programmers to do it for you, however, all you could do is to filter and analyze the logs by your own script on a schedule, and delete the original logs.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [generic solution](https://gist.github.com/bacloud22/0a2083f30d1ac80e998a0af8c990c1e4) for my environment which is JavaScript. It is an Error (exception) wrapper that according to user options, limit the length of the message and optionally substitute the same errors being thrown (with the same type and message and stack if they are raised in some time window) with a very small hash.

I don't advice to use it without proper tests though.